# Edit Column in SELECT Statement on Navicat SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, macos, navicat

I use NaviCat for SQL Server Lite. On my database I make a

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = 1.
```

Then I get a result. Everything correct. Now if i want to edit one column and click into the column I can't write anything.

Is that possible in this version?

EDIT: I use this on my Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

In Navicat You can't edit the results of a query , you will need to open the table and edit the row directly .